# Filter to block gif tweets on Twitter in an adblocker such as ublock origin

Tags: filter, google-chrome-extension, twitter, adblock, ublock-origin

How to block gif tweets in Twitter by adding a certain filter to such as ublock origin?

Tweets with gif blocked/hidden. Twitter changed recently, old gif block filters not working anymore.

This used to work:
twitter.com##article [data-testid="playButton"][aria-label="Play this GIF"]:upward(article)

But not anymore